# How to append images together?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have a project where I need to apply image filters on a large image. To avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions, I split the original image into smaller parts (tiles) then apply the filters on the smaller tiles.

However, I can't seem to combine the tiles together to create a manipulated image with the same size as the original.

I can't draw on a canvas because the size is too big and it will cause OutOfMemoryExceptions.

So far I tried the following code:

```
try {
    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;

    if (outputStream != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Directory.OCR_IMG + "test-" + i + ".jpg");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            outputStream.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    outputStream.close();
}
```

but the resulting image only contains the first tile.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what this one do `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {`? why 4?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira just used 4 as the number of parts I use

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira isn't the offset parameter for byteArray? not which place in the stream to write?

Comment: oh yeah. i got it wrong. sorry. i think it impossible to using outputstream. maybe you can read [this blog](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-merge-multiple-images-into-one.html)